# How to use a text to calculate target from its similarity in a word2vec model?

Tags: model, nltk, word2vec, target, sentence-similarity

I´m a newbie to nltk and I have a question.
I have a text in a var and it's preprocessed and clean.

`text = "since the history of writing predates the concept of the text most texts were not written with this concept in mind most written works fall within a narrow range of the types described by text theory..."`

I have a loaded model.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec,  KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model_example')
```

Now I have to use the text with the model to search for a term and its similarity.

```
term = 'android'
most_similars = model.wv.most_similar(positive=term)
```

But I don't know how to pass the text to the model and then search for n target candidates. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: The code showin in your question – `most_similars = model.wv.most_similar(positive=term)` – will already return the top-10 most-similar words, with their similarity-scores, for `term` (`'andriod'`). What, specifically, other than that do you want to achieve? (What's the end goal?)

Comment: I have to use the model and the text but the results have to be just the text. I don't know how to filter the model so that it only has the text results. Thank you

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "only has the text results". Do you mean, only the words, without their scores? `just_the_words = [sim_pair[0] for sim_pair in most_similars]`

Comment: I have to filter which of those returned by the model are also in the text

Comment: `just_the_words_in_the_text = [sim_pair[0] for sim_pair in most_similars if sim_pair[0] in text_words]` - for efficient lookup, you might make `text_words` a set, eg: `text_words = set(text_words.split())`

Comment: Thx, it works :)